# Understanding passing this in a medthod call in java

Tags: java, this

Sometimes when I’m learning I just need things explain a little differently than a text book gives. 
With the following code:

```
public class Bar{
    public Bar(){}

    public void foo(Baz baz){
        //  modify some values of baz
    }
}

public class Baz{
    //constructor ommited

    public void method(){
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo(this);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me an explanation of why we’re passing this in the given example code? I took the above example off of another stack overflow question, but I don’t completely understand why you pass the current object into a method call. I do see that it can be used in recursion. 
Can someone explain why there doing this? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: You would pass `this` to another method if you wanted the target method to be able to call the accessible fields and methods of "this" object (the one which is currently executing when the keyword `this` is used). But the code example you give above is so abstract that there's no real answer as to why one object is being passed to another.

Comment: Saying "why" is a bit difficult. In order to modify the Baz object. Think of a class as a template and "this" being a reference to an instance of that template. The class could be "Human", with an instance (this) that represents Eric Jovenitti.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is a reference to object itself. In java we usually parse references. To parse a reference you give a name of an object. When an object wants to parse a reference of itself, it uses 'this'.